# UIImageView is "squished" below my UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to place a `UIImageView` at the top of one of my storyboard view controllers (`UIViewController`) and a `UITableView` below it. In Interface Builder everything looks great. The image is 320x150 and butts right up against the top of the `UITableView`. However, when I run it on the simulator, or device, the image is squished by the size of the navigation bar. I've messed with the resizing options (Aspect to fill, etc.), and some seem better, but none just push all the views down below the navigation bar. What am I doing wrong?

What's weird is it looks like it is pushing down all the content but then squishing the image inside the space reserved for the full image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can sense from question is that your UI components push down a little (by the size of UINavigation bar i.e around 44 px). This is because in Interface builder you must not have UINavigationBar in your view. Go to interface builder and then select "Top Bar" to navigation bar. Now set your views accordingly.

Comment: This was it. Thank you! I just had to click on the main view controller in Interface Builder and then set the "Top Bar" option to "Navigation Bar." Looks like it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a stretchable image by using `-resizableImageWithCapInsets:` of `UIImage`.